# How to convert all primary keys from clustered to nonclustered in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, primary-key, clustered-index

I have a large database with `uniqueidentifier` clustered primary key on every table of it. I want to remove clustered indexes from primary keys and put it on an identity column in every table.

When I want to remove clustered indexes, primary key will be removed too. So I have to create primary keys, again. the script I have wrote doesn't work. please help me

```
------------drop all clustered primary keys and add nonclustered primary keys-------
DECLARE @table NVARCHAR(512), @tablename NVARCHAR(512),
        @sql NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql2 NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql3 NVARCHAR(MAX), 
        @column NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT name As 'Table'
INTO #Indexes
FROM sys.tables 
WHERE name like 'webware%'

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Indexes) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @table = (SELECT TOP 1 [Table] FROM #Indexes)

    SET @column = (SELECT c.name
                   FROM sys.tables t
                   INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
                   INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON i.object_id = t.object_id
                   INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = t.object_id
                   INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id 
                                            AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
                   WHERE i.is_primary_key = 1 
                     AND t.name = @table)

    DECLARE @indexname NVARCHAR(512);

    SET @indexname = (SELECT i.name
                      FROM sys.tables t
                      INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
                      INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON i.object_id = t.object_id
                      INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = t.object_id
                      INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id 
                                               AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
                      WHERE i.is_primary_key = 1 
                        AND t.name = @table)

   SET @sql = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @table + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + @indexname

   SET @sql2 = 'DROP INDEX ' +  @indexname + ' ON ' + @table

   SET @sql3 ='ALTER TABLE ' + @table + ' ADD CONSTRAINT ' + @indexname+ ' PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED(' + @column +')'

   EXEC (@sql);
   EXEC (@sql2);
   EXEC (@sql3);

   DELETE FROM #Indexes WHERE [Table] = @table;
END 

DROP TABLE #Indexes
```

Comment: OK - you have lots of code here, looking mostly OK to me - what's the problem? Does it not do what you want it to do? Do you get an error? If so: **what is** the error??

Comment: there are 2 errors. first: Cannot drop the index 'WebWare_System_SystemType.PK_WebWare_System_SystemType', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Comment: second: The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.WebWare_Membership_UserInRole' and the index name 'PK_WebWare_Membership_UserInRole'. The duplicate key value is (55303843-6d22-4a85-b17f-12826e630cac).
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that while a primary key is both a constraint and an index, it is an index that is created via the constraint. Meaning, you create and drop via `CONSTRAINT` only. Once you drop the constraint, the index will be gone. So, remove `SET @sql2` and the `EXEC (@sql2);`.

Please keep in mind that if you have any foreign keys defined that reference any of these primary keys, those will have to be dropped first and then re-created after this particular operation completes.

You can also save some query complexity by assigning both `@column` and `@indexname` variables at the same time:

```
SELECT @column = c.name,
       @indexname = i.name
FROM sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON i.object_id = t.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = t.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id 
                       AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
WHERE i.is_primary_key = 1 
AND t.name = @table;
```

Comment: @PariaMolayem : for error #1, please make sure that you really can drop that PK. It is at least finding the object else it would say that no object exists with that name. For error #2, I think your assumption of the PK being just the UNIQUEIDENTIFIER field is not always correct, and this table `UserInRole` has a composite key of that field and another, meaning your query needs to be updated to account for composite PKs. Lastly, why the JOIN to Schemas? If all tables are in the same schema, remove that JOIN.

Comment: thanks for advices. now I don't have any error, but still it doesn't work for some tables. when I run '@sql' and '@sql3' just for those tables, it works. but when I run it dynamically in this script, it doesn't work. I don't know what's the problem or where to look for the problem.

Comment: it gives me another error : 'Msg 3733, Level 16, State 2, Line 6
Constraint 'PK_WebWare_Portal_Modules_Related' does not belong to table 'WebWare_System_SchemaInSystem'.
Msg 3727, Level 16, State 0, Line 6
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors' do you know what is it about?

Comment: I have found the problem. table 'WebWare_System_SchemaInSystem' did not have any index from the begining.